# Yahoo Fantasy API intermittent consumer key unknown

Tags: javascript, oauth, yahoo-api

I'm having a strange issue hitting the Yahoo Fantasy API. I've got everything working. Authentication, etc. I can make API calls and get data. However sometimes, what seems to be completely randomly, I receive an error:

```
{
  statusCode: 401,
  data: 
    '{"error":
       {
         "lang":"en-US",
         "description":"Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem=\\"consumer_key_unknown\\", realm=\\"yahooapis.com\\""
       }
     }'
}
```

A simple page refresh and I'm back in business, so obviously my consumer_key is perfectly fine. This happens constantly and I can't figure out why. Is the Yahoo API that unreliable??

Answer (score 1):

The same thing is happening to me. I just retry my requests twice now.

Comment: So are you just checking if it fails, and simply rerunning it? Thought about doing that too, but feared spamming their servers if it fails multiple times... especially if there's a bunch of users and it happens to all of them.